# c++ warning C4114 same type qualifier used more than once

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I got a warning: same type qualifier used more than once

with these prototype:

```
static std::wstring joinWS(const vector<wchar_t*> Vect, const const char* delimiter);
static std::wstring joinWS(const vector<char*> Vect, const const char* delimiter);
```

wchar_t* and char* are different.

There is a way to fix it ?

Thanks you !

Comment: `const const char* delimiter` - double the const, half the fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const` is the type qualifier, and you should not use it twice in the same place like that.

> "It’s like, how much more const could this be? And the answer is none.
> None more const."
> -- Bjarne Stroustrup